# Select Command return Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables:

Table 1 *ExamTB*:

```
 ID   ExamTerm   ExamDate
 1    MidTerm    2017-09-24
 2    FinalTerm  2017-12-01
```

Table 2 *ExamSubMarksTB*

```
 ID  ExamID   ClassID  SubjectID TotalMarks  PassMarks
 1     1         1        1       100          50
 2     1         1        2       100          50
 3     1         1        3       100          50
 4     2         1        1       100          50
 5     2         1        2       100          50
 6     2         1        3       100          50
```

Table 3 *ExamResultTB*

```
ID   ExamID    ClassID    SubjectID  MarksObtain StdID
 1     1           1         1         80         1  
 2     1           1         2         70         1  
 3     1           1         3         60         1
 4     2           1         1         50         1  
 5     2           1         2         72         1  
 6     2           1         3         68         1
```

Now when I create a Stored Procedure the `SELECT` this Select Command returns duplicate rows

```
SELECT ExamResultTB.ExamID
     , ExamTB.ExamTerm
     , ExamTB.ExamDate
     , ExamResultTB.StdID
     , StudentTB.Name
     , StudentTB.FatherName
     , ClassTB.ClassName
     , SubjectTB.Subject
     , ExamResultTB.ObtainMarks
     , ExamSubMarksTB.TotalMarks
     , ExamSubMarksTB.PassMarks
FROM ExamResultTB
     INNER JOIN ExamTB ON ExamResultTB.ExamID = ExamTB.ID
     INNER JOIN ClassTB ON ExamResultTB.ClassID = ClassTB.ID
     INNER JOIN SubjectTB ON ExamResultTB.SubjectID = SubjectTB.ID
     INNER JOIN StudentTB ON ExamResultTB.StdID = StudentTB.ID
     INNER JOIN ExamSubMarksTB ON ExamResultTB.ExamID = ExamSubMarksTB.ExamID
WHERE ExamResultTB.ExamID = 4
     AND ExamResultTB.StdID=1
```

Comment: Just use DISTINCT command prior to columns in select query to avoid duplicate.

Comment: shouldn't one of those _Table 2_  have a different name?

Comment: @YogeshSharma...In my experience, in 90% of cases, `DISTINCT` just hides an error in the query. You should **always** first find out where duplicates come from, and only use `DISTINCT` as a last resort.

Comment: Learn to debug these things yourself.  Start with the simplest query and then add one table at a time.  You'll quickly see where the problem lies.

Comment: thanks i did same as u said and i found that line  INNER JOIN ExamSubMarksTB ON ExamResultTB.ExamID = ExamSubMarksTB.ExamID that line was making error and now with the help of  Arkadiusz workin fine thanks For reply and help

Answer (score 1):

For sure this line make a duplicate row:

```
INNER JOIN ExamSubMarksTB ON ExamResultTB.ExamID = ExamSubMarksTB.ExamID
```

You should do it in this way:

```
INNER JOIN ExamSubMarksTB ON ExamResultTB.ExamID = ExamSubMarksTB.ExamID and 
ExamResultTB.ClassId = ExamSubMarksTB.ClassId and ExamResultTB.SubjectID = 
ExamSubMarksTB.SubjectID
```

Comment: Yes this lines was making Problem and now its working with your Correction Thank u so much i was fighting with this from last Night (y)